# How to loop a function indefinitely (instead of using conventional for-loop)

Tags: javascript

I've got a code that will run a set of 20 images, to make it look like an idle sprite is breathing when idle. This runs perfect when its only one loop.

However I can't get it to repeat that loop indefinitely.

Is there a cleaner and faster way to do what i'm doing?

Enclosing that in another for loop doesn't work. It ends in it never loading.

```
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(images[i], 100, 100);
    }, 100 * i);
}
```

I expect it to keep looping indefinitely.

Comment: Look at `setInterval()`, it will loop automatically for you given a delay in m/s

Comment: @harith-shah Title of this question should be edited for more clarity to help everyone on StackOverflow having similar doubt. "**How do I loop a for loop?**" doesn't make such sense here.

Comment: @AadityaSharma: What do you suggest it be called?(Edit: its been changed)

Comment: @HarithShah I made an edit to the title. Can you confirm if that represents your question precisely?

Comment: @AadityaSharma Its been edited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get rid of the `for` loop, use an interval (the standard way to manage "do something every time period"), and manage the value of `i` inside the callback.

```
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(images[i], 100, 100);
    i++;
    if (i === images.length) i = 0;
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a `while` loop in an `async` function that `await`s a Promise that resolves after 100ms:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async () => {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(images[i], 100, 100);
    await delay(100);
    i = (i + 1) % images.length;
  }
})();
```

Comment: Interesting solution: Why would you prefer this over the more "classical" setInterval() approach?

Comment: From my readings `setInterval` will just take over when time is due. Since JS is single-threaded this is maybe not something you want for something that is just an idle animation. Async is the more gentle approach here. If the reason is different or my logic is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: An `async` function which is waiting on an `await` won't block either, it's not something to worry about